# How to cold start a Blazor WASM app when a client device has no internet or is in airplain mode?

Tags: web-applications, blazor, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching, offlineapps

From an unmodified `service-worker.published.js` of a Blazor Hosted WASM project I was trying(in prod) some offline scenarios on mobile clients where the webapp was "Installed".

And here both Chromium based browsers and Firefox seem to completely fail any means to start without an internet connection with this steps:

1. Install webapp
2. Open it with an internet connection present and login
3. Close the webapp
4. Turn off the internet connection or go in airplain mode
5. Open the installed webapp
6. Fail to load the first page(from cache I guess) without internet connection

Meanwhile if this other offline scenario the app does still work:

1. Install webapp
2. Open it with an internet connection present and login
3. Turn off the internet connection or go in airplain mode
4. Continue the use of the webapp without any issue(except missing actions that require internet connections) as long as I don't close it

In this case is this the fault of the project(so it does require better handling for such scenario) or the browser and the tech behind(PWA) that doesn't support such scenario?

Comment: Fully offline requires additional work on your part to make sure all required resources are cached in the browser and that your service worker will intercept and serve requests when offline. There are plenty of resources online about how to do this.

Comment: @MisterMagoo the cache is there, I can see it, but still it fails to use it